# groovy / grails / hibernate - configure set to be fetched eagerly

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, eager-loading, fetch

We are configuring hibernate with grails using the domain classes. Added:

```
static hasMany = [image:Image]

static fetchMode = [image:"eager"]
```

However, when I pull the object graph each image is not loaded. Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you using [1.0.x configuration style](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/single.html#5.3.4%20Eager%20and%20Lazy%20Fetching).
Take a look into [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.3.4%20Eager%20and%20Lazy%20Fetching).

Try

```
class Collage {
    static hasMany = [image:Image]
    static mapping = {
        image lazy: false
    }
}
```